# F# exception and inner exception property

Tags: f#

in F# i can declare a custom exception like so:
`exception Foo of string`,

which will map the string to the Message property.

how do I declare one that I can later use to raise a caught exception as the inner exception of this one? In other words, how do i do something like (pseudo)

```
try 
   ... 
with e -> raise Foo (message, innerException) where innerException is e?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simple declaration of exceptions using `exception` is limited in many ways. If you want to use other features of standard .NET exceptions (i.e. inner exception), then you can declare exception as a class:

```
open System

type FooException(message:string, innerException:Exception) =
   inherit Exception(message, innerException)
```

You can also provide overloaded constructors, for example if you want to use `null` as a default value for `InnerException`.
The exception can be raised as an ordinary .NET exception using `raise`:

```
raise (new FooException(message, e))
```

Comment: i was afraid you would say that :). I was hoping i could do it with the short declaration. thanks!

Comment: I was afraid too but 1 additional line only, not much